# Efficiently Reading in a lot of Data

Tags: java, android, database

I am currently working on a newspaper app that is supposed to read articles that are currently docx (I can change format). I was wondering what is the best way to reference them to my app so that they can be called with a button press. I'm aware that I can set a separate layout and activity for each article but I have around two hundred articles so that isn't very practical. Here is my custom list view I would like to put articles here as well as in each of my sections.

```
package com.tjo.gmagnaum;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class CustomizedListView extends Fragment {  // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://gmag.hossti.com";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news, container, false);
       songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    list=(ListView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        new RetrieveXML().execute(URL);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList


        // Click event for single list row                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    class RetrieveXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                return parser.getXmlFromUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String xml) {
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
            // looping through all song nodes <song>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
                map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                songsList.add(map);

            }

            adapter=new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), songsList);

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone really cares you can set up a simple domain name (tons of free ones available) and in the control panel of your hosting there should be an FTP file manager where you can add and organize files with a pretty simple url look up perfect for code.  [This is what I used](http://members.000webhost.com/)            hope it helps you guys!